# Which format is this config file in?

Tags: python, perl, config

I have to parse config files which look like this:

```
begin
   key1 "value1"
   key2 "value2"
   begin
         key3 "value3"
         key4 "value4"
   end
end
```

What is this format and is there a ready-made parser I can use (preferably in Perl/Python)?

Comment: It looks roughly like lircrc format.

Comment: Also a bit like this one: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Resource_Script_Reference

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the name of the format, but [Parser::MGC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parser%3a%3aMGC) can make light work of this one.

By defining a simple self-recursive `parse` method that recognises the `begin` blocks as inner scopes, we can build a recursive tree of HASH references from the input.

```
package MyParser;
use base 'Parser::MGC';

use strict;
use warnings;

# Need to exclude linefeeds from the whitespace pattern
sub pattern_ws { qr/[\t ]+/ }

sub parse
{
   my $self = shift;
   my %items;

   $self->sequence_of( sub {
      $self->any_of(
         sub {
            # begin ... end block
            $self->expect( 'begin' );
            $self->commit;
            $self->expect( qr/\n/ );
            $self->scope_of( undef, sub {
               push @{$items{begin}}, $self->parse;
            }, 'end' );
            $self->expect( qr/\n/ );
         },
         sub {
            # key "value"
            my $key = $self->token_ident;
            $self->commit;
            $items{$key} = $self->token_string;
            $self->expect( qr/\n/ );
         },
      )
   });

   return \%items;
}
```

This can be printed at the end, perhaps using `Data::Dump`:

```
use Data::Dump 'pp';
print STDERR pp(MyParser->new->from_file(\*STDIN));
```

This gives

```
{
  begin => [
    {
      begin => [{ key3 => "value3", key4 => "value4" }],
      key1  => "value1",
      key2  => "value2",
    },
  ],
}
```